# Height constraint with a constant is not "stable"

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, autolayout

I'm adding a height constraint (set to **300px**) as follows:

```
    [parentView_ addConstraints:@[
          [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:containerView_ 
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                              toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                              multiplier:1.0f constant:300],
          ]];
```

`parentView_` has a subview called `containerView_`.

`containerView_` has two subviews: `view1` and `view2`

I then add button that invokes the following function once tapped:

```
    [containerView_ removeConstraints:[containerView_ constraints]];
    [containerView_ addConstraints:@[
          [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view1 
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                              toItem:view2 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                              multiplier:someVal1 constant:someVal2],
          ]];
```

`someVal1` and `someVal2` change between tap to tap (I'm controlling the values).

**Problem:**

During the first taps, the height of containerView_ changes from 300 to 299 (randomaly!), and then back to 300 and it doesn't look good (looks like the view is growing and shrinking).

I've verified this by overriding `layoutSubviews` and printing `containerView_`'s frame.

What might cause the height to change from 300 to 299, even though I've set a contraint that says **300** (and nothing else!)?

Comment: Can you post a sample project that presents this issue?

Comment: @ArkadiuszHolko Sample project can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B12xiY972a29SEI4RkZoZXVQdDQ/edit?usp=sharing). It might not reproduce on the 1st run, so give it a few shots until you see in the console "WRONG HEIGHT DETECTED"

Comment: @ArkadiuszHolko Forgot to mention: There's a blue UISlider on the right - try to move it, it triggers a constraint removal/addition which causes the height to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample project contains the full list of constraints that were applied, amongst them:

SampleSlider.m:59

```
   [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:slider_ attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                   toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                               multiplier:1.0 constant:0]
```

Changing this constraint to

```
   [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:slider_ attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                   toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                               multiplier:1.0 constant:0]
```

Solved the issue. It appears as a CenterY constraint isn't precise, or floor()'d/ceil()'d to different values on each run.

The funny thing I found is as follows: During two different runs I printed out the frame (who's height was supposed to be 300):

```
<SampleSlider: 0x8988bd0; frame = (12 -1; 56 301); layer = <CALayer: 0x894e4b0>>
<SampleSlider: 0x894f260; frame = (12 1; 56 299); layer = <CALayer: 0x894b770>>
```

Notice the y position - instead of staying steady at 0, it jumps around to -1, 1
Alongside with the height (301, 299) respectively. Set aside the y positioning issue, the frame's height is what's really bothering:

Although the following linear equation is used (or so it appears?), it does not satisfy the constraint in any way:

```
frameHeight = constraintHeight - y
```

As in:

```
301 = 300 - (-1)
```

(so actual height is abs(-1) + 301 = 302)

for the first frame above, and,

```
299 = 300 - 1
```

(so actual height is 299 - 1 = 298)

For the second frame.
Smells funny, doesn't it? seems like someone made a mistake and subtracted the y value instead of adding it.

Changing the equation (hypothetically meaning) to

```
frameHeight = constraintHeight + y
```

Yields

`frameHeight = 300 + -1 = 299`

for the first frame, so actual height is now 300 (y = -1, h = 299)

`frameHeight = 300 + 1 = 301`

for the second frame, so actual height is 300 again (y = 1, h = 301)